# Limit to 1 result for Google Map Places search box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to limit to 1 result for [this sample API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) from Google.

I know I can limit it by restricting the array, but currently sometimes if I limit it, the result is not totally accurate: if the result array has 2 or more items, the first result in the array is not the place I was searching and if I look in the 2 or 3 more results, it's in that place that I was searching.

Is there a way to limit it by one but it shows the accurate place among other array item results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

never mind I already found the answer on this link, thanks again (thx dda for editing my post)

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/places/2012-may-hangout/autocomplete.html?r=290